# Youtube Video player doesn't stop on closing popup

Tags: jquery

I know there are lot of popup plugins available to display the youtube videos. But my client has already a popup in his system and he wants to use the same popup to display the video. Now problem is video is not getting stop when I close the popup. I tried add so many pieces of code from different blogs but no luck due to lack programming knowledge :( Would you please help me in this? Please see the fiddle below.

http://jsfiddle.net/awaises/rsr9ojyL/6/

```
(function() {

            var dlgtrigger = $( '[data-dialog]' );
             console.log(dlgtrigger);
            var somedialog = document.getElementById( dlgtrigger.attr( 'data-dialog' ) );
        var     dlg = new DialogFx( somedialog );

            dlgtrigger.click( dlg.toggle.bind(dlg) );

        })();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/rsr9ojyL/15/

DialogFx have event `onCloseDialog`